# What control over iPhone can Microsoft Authenticator have?

Tags: ios, ms-office

I use Microsoft Outlook and Teams on my private iPhone to access corporate accounts in my employer's network. At some point, the apps refused to access corporate data and asked to register the device via Microsoft Authenticator in corporate system. What control over my iPhone or Outlook and Teams applications such registration gives to my employer? My iPhone is not a managed device, nor is it registered in Settings > General > VPN & Device Management.

Comment: Is this about Authenticator (which mainly is a 2FA app) or about Outlook/Teams? In Outlook/Teams, do you only have your corporate account or also private ones?

Comment: @nohillside I have only corporate accounts configured in Outlook and Teams. The question is both about the control over the whole iPhone and over Outlook/Teams apps that the employer's admin have and also about if registering in Authenticator changes anything related to the control.

Comment: Your employer‘s admin only control the server side of things.

Comment: @nohillside And in case I would have private accounts in Outlook or Teams, would he be also able to wipe the data related to these accounts?

Comment: They don‘t have your login credentials, how would they be able to do so?

Comment: @nohillside I meant the data related to private accounts stored on the device